# DVR monitoring through Terminal Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, video

I'm trying to view my CCTV cameras through a terminal server session using windows server 2008 R2 inside my network. I'm using the Graphical Interface Software of the DVR. The problem is that when I try to view the cameras it doesn't display any image at all.

I already enabled video and audio playback on the terminal server following this instructions:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759165.aspx

I suspect that might be a problem with the video on the server side, because any type of video I try to view is displayed choppy.

My server specifications are:
Windows Server 2008
No video Card
32GB RAM
64-bit Operating System